# How to split Google Analytics reports by a website users?

Tags: google-analytics

This is a sample scenario:

- In a blog website, many bloggers publish his posts.
- You can find a post through a search box.
- You can read the post on a page.

And this is the requirement: Create a blogger's dashboard, connect with Google Analytics and show reports.

- Report by pageview. To do that I'm looking at:

  ```
  ga('set', 'blogger_id', '1234');
  ```
- Report by items showed in the results list (from the search box). To do that I'm looking at send item hits for each result in the list.

  ```
  ga('send', {
      hitType: 'item',
      blogger_id: 1234,
      item_id: 9
  });
  ```

I'm able to connect with GA Api. But I'm not sure how to filter this data and report to the blogger only analysis based on his posts. Could you confirm me if I am on the way to go? If not, could you provide me how to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: In principle that is how it works, however "blogger_id" and "item_id" are not valid dimensions within Google Analytics so they will not be recorded anywhere. You should read the documentation on how to create and send data to custom dimensions: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets

Comment: Great! Thanks :)